# How to search FTP in Google?

Tags: google-search

I used to be able to do Advanced Search on Google, and search by “type” (can't remember what they called it). It enabled me to choose between HTTP and FTP and probably others.

I need to search FTP sites right now for a driver, and can't find the place in Google Advanced Search to choose that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something you can start with

`-inurl:www inurl:ftp intitle:"Index of"`

You would need to fine tune it for the desired file sought.

Comment: That seems to work well, I'll just have to keep coming back to this question to cut and paste.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually tell Google to search for FTP files in the basic search interface using the construct:

```
search terms filetype:ftp
```

There are also [specialist FTP search tools](http://www.google.com/Top/Computers/Internet/Protocols/FTP/Searching/) available that might give you a bit more control of your search.

Comment: The filetype (alternate is ext:) searches for ".ftp" (which is used a lot as a file extension.  It catches a lot of ftp sites, but doesn't search them specifically.  I went through all of the [Google Advanced Search operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators.html#filetype), and couldn't find one that would work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the simple syntax given below:

```
inurl:ftp -inurl:(http|https) "Type Your search content here"
```